# How to create a "Cross" as a template to Checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, expression-blend

I am looking to create something like this. Instead of the regular checkbox, I want to display a grey color 'x' (checkbox checked) and this glowing red cross mark (checkbox unchecked).

[image]

Basically, I have a checkbox added as a datatemplate to `<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>` and I let the users uncheck (not delete) rows from the RadGridView. So instead of a boring checkbox, I thought of designing something like this. This is because, checking does not make sense in my context but unchecking few rows of data does..

I see a solution here: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24433-how-to-create-a-diagonal-cross-symbol

However, I would want to create a cross (not with 2 straight lines), rather something similar to the one shown.

I am very new to XAML and WPF, so I do not know how to proceed in building something like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet would be to try and find something already made. There are places you can download XAML icons, like [xamalot](http://www.xamalot.com/) (appears to be down at the moment)

If you want to do it yourself, then you're not going to reproduce something like the above by hand coding XAML. You'll need to use a graphical editor like Expression Blend.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, usually there are like 1000+ rows in RadGridView. Using an icon would slow things down. Could you please throw some insight on how to use Blend to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Using an icon would slow things down". Icons in WPF are just XAML like everything else, including the default checkbox.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the default checkbox is an icon too?! I thought since we have so many rows, if there are so many icons, then it would increase the time to load the gridview control. I will look into xaml icons now. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the icon used for the checkbox through the Control Template. [This link](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-styling-appearance-edit-control-templates-blend.html) will bring you to a tutorial on how to edit the Control Template.

Since you're targeting the checkbox, you'll need to drill in a little deeper. You'll be editing the ItemTemplate of editing a couple templates down. I have extracted the entire template for you, but I will wait for your answer before posting it. Its not small.